# Cassandra as a Windows Service

Tags: windows, service, cassandra

I just installed [Apache Casandra 1.2.1](http://cassandra.apache.org/download/) on Windows Server 2012 (It's a VM). I double clicked cassandra.bat and it worked without an error.

How can I run Cassandra.bat as a Windows Service, so I can sign out from cumputer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

cassandra.bat file also helps you to run Cassandra as a Windows Service. You just need **Commons Daemon Service Runner** Windows binaries.

You will need to create a folder named **daemon** under the **bin** directory and extract the correct version (32/64 bit) of prunsrv.exe to this directory (**bin\daemon**).

Run command prompt and change directory to the bin. Type;

*cassandra.bat install*

Then run services.msc command to see *cassandra*(yes, lowercased) as a Windows Service.

You can also download

[Datastax Community Edition](http://www.datastax.com/products/community)

or

[Cassandrows](http://kimola.com/products/cassandrows)

which easily install, configure and run Apache Cassandra as a Windows Service.

Comment: are they free solutions for both development and production?

Comment: If you mean Datastax CE and Cassandows, Datastax CE is only free for development (http://www.datastax.com/products/community/platforms) But they also provide a greate web based monitoring solution for Cassandra. Cassandrows is just a packaged distribution of Apache Cassandra and completely free.

Comment: @MustafaSavas DataStax Community Edition is free for use in production as well, it's just that DataStax does not officially "support" production environments on Windows