# Cassandra remote connection failed after installing it as a service

Tags: c#, cassandra, datastax, datastax-java-driver

At first I had a remote connection that worked perfectly fine, I could access it through C# and execute queries onto it.

But I wanted Cassandra to run as a service so I could logout and followed the following link: [Cassandra as a Windows Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14684922/cassandra-as-a-windows-service) and installed the datastax edition.

On a local machine this works perfectly. It runs as a server and I also can execute queries.

But when I run Cassandra as a service on a remote machine. I get the following error message:

> An unhandled exception of type 'Cassandra.NoHostAvailableException' occurred in Cassandra.dll
>
> Additional information: None of the hosts tried for query are available (tried: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9042)

The datastax edition installed another version of Cassandra side by side the old Cassandra. I tried stopping the server and connecting manually to the old cassandra environment, but this is also impossible, my guess is that this happens because of the java drivers installed by the datastax edition, but i am unsure of this.

Is there a tutorial available about how to setup remote connection with cassandra running as a service? Or is there an obvious point I might have missed during the setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you see this kind of errors, there are multiple things you need to check:

1. **Firewall** :  For local connections, firewall is generally not an issue, but when you expose your service over network, firewall might not allow connections from outside
2. **Listen Address**: `listen_address: localhost` in `cassandra.yaml` in your "conf" folder needs to be changed to `listen_address:IP_ADDRESS` so that service is exposed on network instead of loop back locally

Check your `cassandra.yaml` for native_port and listen_native_port options, and see if they are enabled (they seem to be fine because you can connect locally)